# Installed packages are not available inside container image

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, airflow

The code below didn't install some of the packages (tidyverse", "odbc") in docker. When running dockerfile it doesn't show an error but afterward running DAG (running my r script), it shows an error saying that couldn't find the package (tidyverse", "odbc").

Why is that? 'http://cran.rstudio.com' kinda should contain "tidyverse" and "odbc".

---

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:1.10.12-python3.8

USER root

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y vim
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get install -y r-base

RUN echo "r <- getOption('repos'); r['CRAN'] <- 'http://cran.rstudio.com'; options(repos = r);" > ~/.Rprofile
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('DBI')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dplyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dbplyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('magrittr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('furrr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lubridate')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('future')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('jsonlite')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('odbc')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"

USER airflow

# Copy files
COPY . ./

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Python path
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow"

RUN airflow initdb
```

---

As I'm struggling with some packages, the R.file can be as easy as:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")
print("text")
```

---

The error after running R.file in DAG:

```
INFO - Error in library("tidyverse") : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’.
```

So there is "dplyr", but there isn't "tidyverse".

A

Comment: You’ll need to construct a minimal example and show the complete Dockerfile and usage script.

Comment: General suggestion, especially for something time / storage constrained like containers: unless you need most of the packages loaded by tidyverse, you might be better off installing & loading the individual packages that you _do_ need. You've also already installed several tidyverse packages individually anyway

Comment: It’s possible that the issue is caused by your changing the user after installing packages: individual user accounts use separate package libraries. That said, the root user normally *doesn’t* have its own package library under `r-base`; it uses `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. And that path should be searched by all users. But  maybe it isn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph's comment (changing user) is good, I suggest you add a call to `.libPaths()` before package installation to see where they will be installed. Also, `~/.Rpofile` is relative to the user, you write it *before* changing to the `airflow` user. (BTW, `install.packages(c('DBI','odbc'))` works, you can install multiple packages in one command call instead of repeatedly calling `Rscript`; not a bug, just a comment.)